# Why won't my UITableView rotate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Within Interface Builder, I have the following

```
UIViewController
-- View
---- TableView
```

In my UIViewController I have set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

I also have other view controllers that are in IB. What am I missing here? The only way I can get it to rotate is if I use the transform method.

Comment: So is the UIView that *contains* the table view *also* controlled by a UIViewController for which the autorotation is set to YES?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the tableview in a tab-based app by any chance? In case you are, you can only get a view to support landscape mode if all the viewcontrollers of the tabbar controller support landscape mode.

Other than that, I don't see any reason why your view should not support landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the autosizing settings.  To be more specific, in Interface Builder, make sure autoresizing is clicked, then in the Size Inspector, make sure the tableview all it's superviews of the table view have red arrows filled in on the top, left, right, and also select the two internal arrows.

I am wondering if the questioner actually had the table view in a subview of the main view.  I see this behavior for a table view that is one level deeper in the view hierarchy:

- Main View
- - Subview
- - - Table View

By default, the Main View has it's autosizing arrows set up correctly, but if you add an additional view, it does not.

In response to the question about the problem being with multiple view controllers: Note that a UIViewController is not a UIView's delegate.  In fact, it looks like chain of events goes the other way - first the system sees an autorotation and tells the UIViewControllers about it.  If the UIViewControllers have shouldAutoresize returning yes, then the UIViewControllers resize their main views.  The resizing of the main views can automatically cause their subviews to resize if they are set correctly.

According to Apple docs, you should not have multiple view controllers controlling different parts of a view - for example a separate tableview controller for a table view that is in a subview of the main view - because it mucks with the event chain - you could see how that would be the case here.  Don't know if that's helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and it works as expected. You will need to provide more detail, I think. In my experience, when a view "fails" to rotate, that's because some view controller somewhere is telling it not to. Check to make sure all your view controllers are returning the right values from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Answer (score 0):

if your are using storyboard, your VC contains a UITableview, check if your Scene have AutoLayout unchecked.