# MWPhotoBrowser Doesn't Rotate To Landscape When Used in Tab Bar Navigation App

Tags: iphone, landscape

I'm developing my First iOS App. It's a simple Tab Bar Navigation App with Custom Buttons that are linked to a Photo Gallery.

The App uses MWPhotoBrowser Library for the Gallery Functionality.

The gallery works perfectly except it doesn't rotate to Landscape Orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
NSLog(@"ShouldAutoRotate CALLED! - The FIELD");
return YES;}

- (IBAction)showRenderings:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MWPhoto *photo;

photo = [MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"field_rendering_1" ofType:@"jpg"]];
photo.caption = @"The Field Rendering 1";
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"field_rendering_2" ofType:@"jpg"]];
photo.caption = @"The Field Rendering 2";
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"field_rendering_3" ofType:@"jpg"]];
photo.caption = @"The Field Rendering 3";
[photos addObject:photo];

_photos = photos;

// Create MWPhotoBrowser
MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

browser.displayActionButton = YES;
browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[browser setInitialPageIndex:0];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

}

I checked all `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` in my View Controller and MWPhotoBrowser. They all return YES.

Why the MWPhotoBrowser doesn't rotate to Landscape Orientation?

Comment: Having the same problem. However, I made an example and run it directly from AppDelegate and it worked. When integrated it in another class, suddenly it did not work to rotate to landscape. Have you tested if this occurs for you too?

Answer (score 2):

When you use navigation controller for multiple orientations in that case you need to create subclass of UINavigationController then make appropriate code for orientations support in that subclass then use it in your application. [here](http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/) some example code so you can take a look..

Answer (score 1):

As written as a comment in your question I had the same problem.

My problem was that I was using a Tabbar.
The secret with Tabbar and rotation is that all viewcontrollers in the tabbar must support landscape mode. Do this by returning YES in this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Reference: [Why won't my UITableView rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/686005/373455)

Worked like charm for me after that correction!